# Why doesn't columns.render execute when DataTable().draw() is called?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I'm puzzled to why [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) is not included in the execution pipeline of [DataTable().draw()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()).

An example:

**HTML**

```
<table id="data">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>TimeColumn</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>234</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>345</td>
            <td>456</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>567</td>
            <td>678</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button id="refresh">Refreh</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#data').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [{
            targets: 0,
            render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                return data + ' time:' + Date.now();
            }
        }]
    });

    $('#refresh').on('click', function() {
        $('#data').DataTable().draw();
    });
});
```

The expected result when clicking the `Refresh` button is that the time value should advance in the first column, but it doesn't.
The assigned render function is never called after initialization.

([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1t05jxLb/) of the example.)

Is there any workaround or do I have to dig into the code of [DataTables](http://datatables.net/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of destroying the datatable and repopulating it I ended up modifying `jquery.datatables.js` version `1.10.2`.

The main issue is that the line 1935 in `jquery.datatables.js` checks if the row is already created:

```
if ( aoData.nTr === null )
{
  _fnCreateTr(oSettings, iDataIndex);
}
```

One option to remedy this is to set `aoData.nTr = null`. But this might break other functionality or cause unwanted side effects so this is not an acceptable solution.

I opted to instead add an argument to the `.draw()` function (line 7137) and adding a setting called `bForceReDraw` (`draw()` already takes an argument so we add a second argument):

```
_api_register('draw()', function (resetPaging, forceReDraw) {
  return this.iterator( 'table', function ( settings ) {
    settings.bForceReDraw = forceReDraw === true;
      _fnReDraw(settings, resetPaging === false);
  } );
} );
```

Then I changed the `null` check on line 1935 to:

```
if ( aoData.nTr === null || oSettings.bForceReDraw === true )
{
  _fnCreateTr(oSettings, iDataIndex);
}
```

In the function `_fnCreateTr()` there is also a `null` check on `nTr` (line 1586) so I needed to modify that as well:

```
if ( row.nTr === null || oSettings.bForceReDraw === true )
{
  nTr = nTrIn || document.createElement('tr');
  ...
```

Now we simply call `draw()` with the new argument and everything works as expected.

```
$('#data').DataTable().columns.adjust().draw(false, true);
```

Comment: I'm not keen on modifying the source code itself to fix the problem. I'd say it has a higher chance to do damage than good.

Comment: That's your prerogative. The modifications should have no side effects at all since I'm adding a setting that is not referenced anywhere else. The rerender of the row happens only when `draw()` is explicitly called with `true` as the second argument. Otherwise the default behavior is executed.

Comment: agree with @SaniHuttunen, like most other jQuery plugins, each version of dataTables has errors and blunders, as in this case, and dataTables as a whole cannot meet each and every programmers demands. 1) look for a "native" solution 2) look for a workaround 3) implement the desired feature yourself. +1 for a good job.

Comment: Wow, glad you hunted this down.  This conceivably just saved me hours.  And - about a year later - the bug is still present.  Guess that must mean that this use-case is quite rare.

Comment: There is another solution :  table.rows().invalidate().draw();

Comment: @Sani: Works fine for me though. But I'm using a JS-array as data source instead of table content as you are. Perhaps that makes the difference.

Comment: @Pier: Might be. But I suspect the problem lies in the way the render function is executed in the pipeline. Since this was a while ago I don't exactly remember how it works. But you are certain the render function is indeed executed when invalidating the rows with a JS-array as the data source?

Comment: @Sani: Yes. I've defined the DataTable once with the array of data. Afterwards, with the single line of code above, the whole table is re-rendered. As the rendering depends on some global js variables that have changed meanwhile, I can easily confirm the new execution of the rendering function. But I just saw that I'm not using  the "render" parameter for the function but the "mRender" parameter of the column definition. Are they the same ?

Comment: @Pier: `mRender` is probably the pre-1.10 version name of `render`. But indeed you are correct. The table is refreshed and the render function is executed when the data source is a javascript array. Strange behaviour indeed and points to that something is wrong in the render pipline when the data source is table content. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wew94z9v/)

Answer (score 3):

Everybody has problems dynamically reloading DataTables.
Consider this approach. Destroy the DataTable first to re-render.

```
var dataSet = [];

if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#yourTable')) {
    $('#yourTable').DataTable({
        "destroy": true,
        "processing": true,
        "data": dataSet
    });
} else {
    $('#yourTable').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "data": dataSet
    });
}
```

Comment: Not keen on destroying the DataTable and repopulating it. Ended up modifying the datatables.js source instead.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen, please post your solution as an accepted answer. Perhaps it will help other people in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I found that, contrary to `.draw()`, `.columns.adjust().draw();` will fire the `render` function again. But, unfortunately, it doesn't re-render the table... (?)

The only workaround I found is to `.destroy()` the table, replace `$('#data').html()` with its original contents and start again with `$('#data').DataTable({ columnDefs: colDefs });`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table_data = $('#data').html();

    var colRender = function (data, type, row, meta) {
        var today = new Date();
        var ms = today.getMilliseconds();
        var ss = today.getSeconds();
        var mn = today.getMinutes();
        var hh = today.getHours();
        var time = ' time:' + hh + ':' + mn + ':' + ss + ':' + ms
        console.log('data+time', data + time);
        return data + time;
    }

    var colDefs = [{
        targets: 0,
        render: colRender
    }];
    
    $('#data').DataTable({
        columnDefs: colDefs
    });

    $('#refresh').click(function () {
        // $('#data').DataTable().columns.adjust().draw();
        // $('#data').DataTable().draw();
        $('#data').DataTable().destroy();
        $('#data').html(table_data);
        $('#data').DataTable({
            columnDefs: colDefs
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="data">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>TimeColumn</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>234</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>345</td>
            <td>456</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>567</td>
            <td>678</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="refresh">Refresh</button>
```

Comment: Yes I noticed that aswell that `.columns.adjust()` will execute render but as you say it doesn't draw the new values. I'm not keen on destroying the DataTable and repopulating it. Ended up modifying the datatables.js source instead. The main issue was `DataTable.models.oSettings.nTr` is set on initialization and when redrawing the table it checks (line 1935 in 1.10.2) if it's null or not. If it's null then it creates the row otherwise it uses the old value.