# Vue3 + DataTables redraw the table after delete

Tags: ajax, datatables, vuejs3, redraw

I have a Vue3 component that renders tables based on model data. Then I add DataTables functionality to the table to be able to filter and sorting data. Everything works fine. But if I click on the delete button I need to send a delete ajax request to the server and then on success redraw the whole table with new data. I tried to use draw() method but it does not work. Deleted rows are still in the table. I don't know if I need to remove the whole table and create it again or there is another solution.
This is the Vue template code.

```
<template>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table :id="id" class="table table-bordered nowrap" width="100%;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Visible</th>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="article in articles" :key="article.id">
                    <td>{{article.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{article.title}}</td>
                    <td>{{article.visible}}</td>
                    <td>{{article.user.name}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" @click.prevent="deleteArticle(article.id)" class="text-danger">delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
```

And this is the deleteArticle() code

```
deleteArticle(id) {
    axios.get( apiRoutes.ARTICLE_DELETE_URL + id )
        .then( response => {
            this.getArticles();
        })
        .catch( response => {
            console.log(response);
        }); 
},

getArticles() 
{
    axios.get( apiRoutes.ARTICLES_URL )            
        .then((response) => {
            this.articles = response.data.articles;

            this.$nextTick(function() {
                this.setDataTable();
            });
        })
        .catch((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        });
},

setDataTable() {
    var table = $('#'+this.id);

    if( this.dataTableObject ) 
    {
        this.dataTableObject.reload().draw();  // This is the code I need to fix
        return;
    }

    ...
},
```

What is the right flow of this component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't columns.render execute when DataTable().draw() is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25922255/why-doesnt-columns-render-execute-when-datatable-draw-is-called)

Comment: In short: Use Json or modify the DataTables source to fix.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen can you be more specific? What it means source? The source is the html code in this case.

Comment: The source for DataTables. (jquery.datatables.js). Se the other question and answers linked above.

Comment: An alternative is to re-render everything. But that is sometimes not what you want since it can be slow, if you have many rows in the table.

Comment: No I wont to change source code to fix it. Hope there is another proper solution.

Comment: The proper solution is to change the source code. Anything else is a workaround.

Comment: I dont agree. also I need to join the code from the table with Vue methods.

Comment: How do you fix a bug? Correct the problemematic code or work around the problem?